# Memory warning when assigning new value to __autoreleasing inout parameter incorporating old value under ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

I am implementing key-value validation like so:

```
- (BOOL)validateValue:(__autoreleasing id *)value forKey:(NSString *)key error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    NSAttributeDescription *attribute = [[self.entity attributesByName] objectForKey:key];
    if (attribute && attribute.attributeType == NSStringAttributeType) {
        *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ modified", *value];
        return YES;
    }
    return [super validateValue:value forKey:key error:error];
}
```

When this runs, memory continually increases until the app receives a memory warning and crashes at the 250 MB mark.

Interestingly with the following variations the total memory footprint remains stable at around 5 MB.

```
*value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", *value];
*value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ modified", NSStringFromClass([self class])];
```

With the first variation, I suspect +stringWithFormat is optimised to simply return *value unchanged.

The second variation is just me trying to make sure the compiler or objective c runtime isn't returning already existing objects without allocating anything new.

It is only when I create a new string object incorporating the passed in value that memory increases.

I've tried doing

```
NSString * __unsafe_unretained tmp = *value;
*value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ modified", tmp];

CFStringRef tmp = (__bridge_retained CFStringRef)*value;
*value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ modified", tmp];
CFRelease(tmp);
```

To no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you overrider `validateValue:forKey:error:`? The `NSManagedObject` documentation states: "You typically should not override validateValue:forKey:error:, instead you should implement methods of the form validate<Key>:error:, as defined by the NSKeyValueCoding protocol."

Comment: It's the same validation code for all string properties. I don't want to repeat myself in each individual validation method.

Answer (score 0):

> Incidentally, notice that you don't need to write `(__autoreleasing id *)`; just writing `(id *)` is good enough. ARC assumes that pointers-to-object-pointers are `__autoreleasing` by default. In fact, the [Apple documentation on Key-Value Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Validation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002173) has just `(id *)` for this parameter. But this definitely has nothing to do with your memory leak.

Can you post a complete, compilable example? (A Pastebin link might be the appropriate way to do this.)

- Does the memory leak still reproduce if you take Cocoa out of the loop and just directly call your `-validateValue:forKey:error:` method a couple million times?
- Does the memory leak still reproduce if you replace `return [super ...]` with `return YES;`?

> With the first variation, I suspect +stringWithFormat is optimised to simply return *value unchanged.

This is trivial to check, you know? Just make it

```
id oldValue = *value;
*value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", *value];
assert(*value == oldValue);  // TESTING -- is the value unchanged?
```

Indeed, Apple's interning (de-duplicating) of non-mutable `NSString` instances means that your guess is correct. Non-mutable `NSString`s containing the same character data will generally compare pointer-equal. (But of course you shouldn't write code relying on this quirk!)

Personally, my money is on there being no leak at all, but just a lot of (recursive?) calls to  `-validateValue:forKey:error:`. Look, every time you call that function, it takes whatever string *used* to be the value and extends it by `strlen(" modified")` bytes. So the first time you validate `@"foo"`, you get `@"foo modified"`; when you validate *that* you get `@"foo modified modified"`; when you validate *that* you get `@"foo modified modified modified"`; and eventually your program runs out of memory and crashes.

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)validateValue:(id *)value forKey:(NSString *)key error:(NSError **)error
{
    NSAttributeDescription *attribute = [[self.entity attributesByName] objectForKey:key];
    if (attribute && attribute.attributeType == NSStringAttributeType) {
        if ([*value hasSuffix: @" modified"]) {
            NSLog(@"Uh-oh! I refuse to modify an already modified value!");
        } else {
            *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ modified", *value];
        }
        return YES;
    }
    return [super validateValue:value forKey:key error:error];
}
```

Does this solve your memory leak?